# How can I search to see if there's more than one bone with a certain name?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones

I've already figured out the code for finding bones by their name. I just need to know if there's more than one bone that meets this criteria (for example the words: "hand", "ik", and "l").

```
ar = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]

for bone in ar.data.bones:
    if all(words in bone.name for words in ("hand", "ik", "l")):
        Bone.name = "NewName"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for bone in bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.bones:
    bn = bone.name
    if "hand" in bn:
        #do something
    elif "|" in bn:
        # do something else
    if "ik" in bn and "foot" in bn:
        # it's a foot ik
```

The 1. if always triggers as long as "hand" is in the name
The 2. if only triggers when "hand" is not, but "|" is
The 3. is true only when ik and foot are in the name.
There might be a one-liner for this, but this approach should be more flexible and readable
Please note, these are case-sensitive, if you want to ik to be treated the same way as IK, use:

```
bn = bone.name.lower()
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import bpy
ar = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]  # consider bpy.data.armatures

words = ("hand", "ik", "l")
check = lambda b: all(word in b.name for word in words)
# check = lambda b: all(word in b.name.lower() for word in words)
found = [b for b in ar.data.bones if check(b)]
print(f"Found {len(found)} bones with {words=}\n{found}")
```